# Applet - Simple squares and cube with for loop

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint

I need to write an applet that calculates the squares and cubes of the numbers from 0-10 and draws the resulting values in a table format as follows:

Using a for loop.  I made the application and it worked fine.  I am using eclipse and when try to declare a string to be a number.  I receives errors please help! I have  attempted to draw the class from my package and it would not work also.

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 4 8
3 9 27
4 16 64
5 25 125
6 36 216
7 49 343
8 64 512
9 81 729
10 100 1000
```

---

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class countApplet extends Applet 
{

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
        for ( int count = 0 ; count < 10 ; count++ ) 
        {
            count = num1(0); 

            g.drawString( "" , 20  , 20 * ( count + 1 ) );
            g.drawString( "" , 70  , 20 * ( count ^2 ) );
            g.drawString( "" , 120 , 20 * ( count + 1 ) );
        }
    }

}
```

This is my class I attempt to draw from:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class calculate
{

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int num1 = 0;

        System.out.println("Number" +"\t" +"Square" + "\t" + "Cube");   
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
        {

            System.out.println(i +"\t"+ i * i+"\t" + i* i * i);
        }

    }
}
```

Maybe a better explanation of how to use `Math.sqrt` in an applet would help me also?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yes is its due to the teacher.  I cant tell my graduate teacher that ..lol ill really fail.  he showed me what he wanted.

Comment: *"I cant tell my graduate teacher that.."*  You could always drop an anonymous note off to them.  But really they ought to be ashamed of themselves for being so stuck in the past.

Comment: lol he is of age and has a doctrine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error in for loop in your countApplet class.Find the below code

```
for ( int count = 0 ; count < 10 ; count++ ) 
{
    //count = num1(0); 
    g.drawString( String.valueOf(count) , 20  , 20 * ( count + 1 ) );
    g.drawString( String.valueOf(count*count) , 70  , 20 * ( count + 1 ) );
    g.drawString( String.valueOf(count*count*count) , 120 , 20 * ( count + 1 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Naming convention: Class names should start with a capital letter, i.e. `Calculate` instead of `calculate` and `CountApplet`.

Also, having a function called `num1` and a variable with the same name is bad practice.

Besides, you are declaring `num1` ind `main()` but never using it.